# SQL - Join a table and all possibles results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the following tables

```
SELECT C.Id, C.Color
FROM Color AS C

Id    Color
-------------------
 1    Strong Red
 2    Light Red
 3    Strong Blue
 4    Light Blue

SELECT L.Id, L.Place
FROM Location AS L

Id   Place
---------------
 1   Usa
 2   Japan

SELECT V.Id, V.PriceForADay, V.PriceForAWeek, V.ColorId, V.LocationId
FROM Vehicules AS V

Id   PriceForADay  PriceForAWeek ColorId  LocationId 
----------------------------------------------------
 1       10           15           1         1
 2       15           20           2         1
 3       20           25           1         2
```

The result I wish to get is :

```
SELECT 
    C.Id, C.Color, V.PriceForADay, V.PriceForAWeek, V.ColorId,  
    V.LocationId/L.LocationId 
WHERE 
    V.LocationId = 1

Id  Color        PriceForADAy  PriceForAWeek  ColorId  LocationId
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  Strong Red        10            20            1         1
 2  Light Red         15            25            2         1 
 3  Strong Blue       NULL          NULL          NULL      1
 4  Light Blue        NULL          NULL          NULL      1
```

How can I get this desired result? A simple left join + where isn't working.

Thank you

Comment: Join won't work in case you are trying to join 2 tables whose number of rows are different

Comment: this SQL statement is possible when you interlink the tables using Primary/ Foriegn keys, without which Join will not be working.

Comment: Why isn't the left join not working? Show the full query that you've tried please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your result the Strong Blue and Light Blue are in Location 1. 
However the dataset provided do not have those color in location 1.
Also for c.Id(ColorId) 2,3 in result the corresponding ColorId is null in result, which I am guessing is wrong. So the following query is just based on guessed dataset:-

```
DECLARE @Color TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Color VARCHAR(30))
INSERT INTO @Color (Color) VALUES('Strong Red'), ('Light Red'),('Strong Blue'),('Light Blue')

DECLARE @Location TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Place VARCHAR(30))
INSERT INTO @Location (Place) VALUES('USA'), ('Japan')

DECLARE @Vehicules TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, PriceForADay INT, PriceForAWeek INT,
     ColorId INT, LocationId INT)
INSERT INTO @Vehicules(PriceForADay, PriceForAWeek, ColorId, LocationId) VALUES(10,15,1,1),(15,20,2,1),(20,25,1,2)
,(NULL,NULL,3,1),(NULL,NULL,4,1)

--SELECT * FROM @Color
--SELECT * FROM @Location
--SELECT * FROM @Vehicules 

SELECT
    C.Id, C.Color, V.PriceForADay, V.PriceForAWeek, V.ColorId
    ,L.Id AS LocationID
FROM  @Color C LEFT JOIN @Vehicules V ON C.Id = V.ColorId
LEFT JOIN @Location L ON V.LocationId = L.Id
WHERE V.LocationId = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort ! I will mark this answer as correct, since it is, but as you have correctly guessed, i don't have the last two rows on vehicules you inserted. Therefore i cannot achieve what i wanted. Nevertheless Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Write a `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT C.Id,C.Color,V.PriceForADay,V.PriceForAWeek,V.ColorId,  V.LocationId/L.LocationId 
FROM Vehicules AS V 
OUTER APPLY Color AS C
where V.LocationId = 1
```

Read more here:

http://sqlhints.com/tag/outer-apply-examples/

Comment: A full outer join is not returning Strong Blue and White Blue rows. Maybe because of the where ?

Comment: I inserted the where part into the join section

Comment: No, it's giving me all the vehicules, then all the color, meaning if i have 100 vehicules and 3 colors, i get 103 rows, but i want the 300 combinations rows. Thank you tough

Comment: If you want 100 vehicules to be match with colors, then you need to use OUTER APPLY. I have changed the solution

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
select C.Id, C.Color, V.PriceForADAy, V.PriceForAWeek, V.ColorId, L.Id
from Colors AS C left join Vehicules AS V on C.Id = V.ColorId
join Location AS L on V.LocationId = L.Id
where L.Id = 1
```

Comment: No it is not working, i m getting all the vechicules (100) with the missing colors rows at the end (3). Or i need the 300 possibles combinations rows. Thank you tough